# Keras Transformer - Test Loss Not Changing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transformer-model

I'm trying to create a small transformer model with Keras to model stock prices, based off of [this tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/) from the Keras docs. The problem is, my test loss is massive and barely changes between epochs, unsurprisingly resulting in severe underfitting, with my outputs all the same arbitrary value.

My code is below:

```
def transformer_encoder_block(inputs, head_size, num_heads, filters, dropout=0):
    # Normalization and Attention
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(inputs)
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(x, x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    return x + res


data = ...

input = np.array(
    keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(data["input"], padding="pre", dtype="float32"))

output = np.array(
    keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(data["output"], padding="pre", dtype="float32"))

# Input shape: (723, 36, 22)
# Output shape: (723, 36, 1)

# Train data
train_features = input[100:]
train_labels = output[100:]

train_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=3)

# Test data
test_features = input[:100]
test_labels = output[:100]

test_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels, num_classes=3)



inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,22), dtype="float32", name="inputs")

# Ignore padding in inputs
x = layers.Masking(mask_value=0)(inputs)

x = transformer_encoder_block(x, head_size=64, num_heads=16, filters=3, dropout=0.2)

# Multiclass = Softmax (decrease, no change, increase)
outputs = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax", name="outputs"))(x)

# Create model
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Compile model
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005)), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model
history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

# Evaluate on the test data
test_loss = model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", test_loss)

out = model.predict(test_features)
```

After padding, `input` is of shape `(723, 36, 22)`, and `output` is of shape `(723, 36, 1)` (before converting output to one hop, after which there are 3 output classes).

Here's an example output for ten epochs (trust me, more than ten doesn't make it better):

```
Epoch 1/10
20/20 [==============================] - 2s 62ms/step - loss: 10.7436 - accuracy: 0.3335
Epoch 2/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 62ms/step - loss: 10.7083 - accuracy: 0.3354
Epoch 3/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 60ms/step - loss: 10.6555 - accuracy: 0.3392
Epoch 4/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 62ms/step - loss: 10.7846 - accuracy: 0.3306
Epoch 5/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 60ms/step - loss: 10.7600 - accuracy: 0.3322
Epoch 6/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 59ms/step - loss: 10.7074 - accuracy: 0.3358
Epoch 7/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 59ms/step - loss: 10.6569 - accuracy: 0.3385
Epoch 8/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 60ms/step - loss: 10.7767 - accuracy: 0.3314
Epoch 9/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 61ms/step - loss: 10.7346 - accuracy: 0.3341
Epoch 10/10
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 62ms/step - loss: 10.7093 - accuracy: 0.3354
Test loss: [10.073813438415527, 0.375]
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step
```

Using the same data on a simple LSTM model with the same shape yielded a desirable prediction with a constantly decreasing loss.

Tweaking the learning rate appears to have no effect, nor does stacking more `transformer_encoder_block()`s.

If anyone has any suggestions for how I can solve this, please let me know.

Comment: A learning rate of 0.5 is huge, decrease it.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy it was at 0.005 before, same problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell but there's a few things you could try:
- Remove dropout
- Try an even smaller learning rate like 1e-5
Also, can you run model.summary() for more info?

Comment: You use a different way to built the model than shown in the tutorial. Your model uses one encoder block whereas the tutorial uses four encoder blocks stacked on each other.  Because you use a different model architecture than given in the tutorial I would also expect different results. Since your model is less deep than the model in the tutorial I expect your model to converge faster and achieve a lower final performance, which seems to be the case. Can you try to replicate the model architecture in the tutorial, report the results, and adjust your model from that architecture?

Comment: It seems the model is learning very slowly, So it shows very less change in the model performance. Please try again by using default `learning_rate=0.01` for Adam optimizer as well by removing all the `dropout` layers from the model definition. Let us know if the issue still persists.